# Grails Events Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, session, grails

I have a integration with another systems and i'm using the platform core to support this. But when i save a domain class and send it to a topic listener, the received message contains this attributes:

```
data: br.com.domains.Booking : 1
event: createBooking
gormSession: true
headers: {hash: (...)}
namespace: app
```

But when i'm access of this way:

```
booking.channel.id
```

A `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` is throwered.

I tried to use the `attach()` but the problem is not solved.

What's is the solution for this? Use a criteria or HQL to query all values i need in database and why the session is closed if the attribute `gormSession` is showing `true`.

** The session in my controller is flushed

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Yep. The problem is in a transaction if a request to another server is required, the transaction is not closed and committed in time, the solution is finish the transaction before call the server.
* the listener call another url.